# How do I design a table that records a customer's state within a time span?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have a `Customer` table with an `IsActive` column. If "active", he is eligible for certain products and services.

I need to know whether *on a certain date*, he was eligible, or not.

Problem is his record can change, so I must track of those changes in a  `CustomerChanges` audit table which contains those properties that can be changed. Whenever we change his record, we add a record to that table, with the changes and the date.

What I need is "get me all customers, who on date xyz, were active".

*How would I model and query such a table?*

(I'm using SQL Server and EF Core)

---

Silly example: send customer a gift card for his birthday, but only if his account was not suspended, or canceled, or in arrears, etc. In other words, only if his account was "active" on that date.

Comment: So basically you just need to know if a user was active during the last entry prior to the selected date?  (As anything later then the date is irrelevant, and only the most recent change prior to the date would be indicative of them being active for that specific date).

Comment: @JBS I suppose so. But there could be 100 state changes. So I need to know he was active on that specific date.

Comment: Sure, but the only state change relevant to you would be the most recent one prior to that date.  Even if they go from inactive to active and back 50 times, it's only the last state that matters.  Put another way, only the latest state (from the perspective of the chosen date) is the "active" state.

Comment: @JBC Yes. Is there a way to perform such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in theory this is what you're trying to achieve.

```
select Users.Id, Users.UserName, OrderedActivity.IsActive
from
(
    select UserActivity.Id
        , UserActivity.UpdateTime
        , UserActivity.IsActive
        , row_number() over         
         (partition by UserActivity.Id order by UserActivity.UpdateTime desc) as EntryNum
    from UserActivity
    where UserActivity.UpdateTime <= '20161210 10:00:00 AM'
) OrderedActivity
inner join Users
    on Users.Id = OrderedActivity.Id     
where OrderedActivity.EntryNum = 1;
```

Essentially it's ranking the entries in UserActivity by date (which contain any active/inactive changes), excluding anything more recent than the selected date.  It then takes the first entry (the most recent change prior to the date).

At this point, for each User record, you have a corresponding IsActive flag to do with as you will (you can just filter off what you don't want here with another where clause added to the outer query).

Here's an example of this in action: http://rextester.com/QPSM50121

In C#:

```
var filteredActivity = 
    Activity.Where(activity => activity.UpdateTime <= SOME_DATE)
            .GroupBy(activity => activity.Id)
            .Select(groupedActivities => groupedActivities.OrderByDescending(activity => activity.UpdateTime).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

var results = 
        from user in Users
        join activity in filteredActivity
            on user.Id equals activity.Id
        where activity.IsActive == 'Y'
        select new { user.Id, activity.IsActive };
```

Example in action: http://rextester.com/SYZ96749

Here's another version in C#, but tried to consolidate it all into LINQ-to-SQL.  Not sure if it'll help with your EF group by problems.

```
var results = 
    from activity in Activity
    where activity.UpdateTime <= Convert.ToDateTime("10/12/2016 10:00:00")
    group activity by activity.Id into groupedActivities
    let mostRecentActivity =
    (
        from groupedActivity in groupedActivities
        orderby groupedActivity.UpdateTime descending
        select groupedActivity
    ).First()
    join user in Users
        on mostRecentActivity.Id equals user.Id
    where mostRecentActivity.IsActive == 'Y'
    select new { user.Id, mostRecentActivity.IsActive };
```

In action: http://rextester.com/QUGR95471

Comment: This is ALMOST perfect, but EF Core [doesn't yet support "group by"](http://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341). What a pity. So technically this answer is correct, but it doesn't solve my problem! :-( Thanks a lot for helping though!

Comment: From reading, it doesn't sound like there's no group by support, just that sometimes it has issues converting it to SQL.  I've added another C# version using most of LINQ-to-SQL that you can try.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way: a table with CustomerId, StartingDate and EndingDate as PrimaryKey. And then you can also have all additional informations you may need in this table, like he was active or not.

And the best way to save all changes, is to set up a trigger on update on your Customer.IsActive.... This trigger needs to difference between the startingpoint of the change and the endingpoint of the change.

And then, if you want to query that, you will need a join between those two tables which looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerChanges
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Id = CustomerChanges.CustomerId
WHERE xyz BETWEEN CustomerChanges.StartingDate 
AND CustomerChanges.EndingDate;
```

Comment: "difference between the startingpoint of the change and the endingpoint of the change" - Yes I've been looking into something similar, but, the "starting date" is "now", and the ending date is in the future. So this design is simple to implement, but it means I must make changes to old records when customer state changes (which is fine, just a little bit complicated). Or maybe I didn't understand your idea?

Comment: yes you understood my idea right. is it really necessary to have a record each time the IsActive changes? 
I don't think that it is too complicated to change an existing value in that table. Perhaps it would be a good idea to have a column like "LastChange" in your Customer table, which saves the timestamp of the last change and then it would be quiet easy to figure out which record of the CustomerChanges should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track and may already have the best design. You failed to show the design of the audit table so here is my suggestion:

```
create table CustomerStatus(
  CustID     int  not null references Customer( ID ),
  EffDate    date not null,
  Status      char( 1 ) not null,   -- A = Active, S = Suspended, etc.
  constraint PK_CustomerStatus primary key( CustID, EffDate )
);
```

Note there is no "End" date. Once a status becomes effective, it remains in effect until it is replaced by another status. That is the key to the query to find either the current status or the status that was in effect on any given date.

```
Select  c.*, cs.Status
from    Customer c
join    CustomerStatus cs
    on  cs.CustID = c.ID
    and cs.EffDate =(
        select  Max( EffDate )
        from    CustomerStatus
        where   CustID = cs.CustID
            and EffDate <= Today() );
```

Don't let the subquery scare you. What you are getting is the one record that contains the status with the latest effective date prior to or the same as the current date/time. You can create a view using the query to return the current status of any or all customers as that will be the status probably most used in operations.

Here's the really cool part. Change the last line to something like this:

```
            and EffDate <= :AsOf );
```

Set the *AsOf* variable to the present date/time and you get the current status as before. Set the variable to any date/time in the past or future and you get the status that was (or will be) effective as of that date/time. You can retrieve the current status or any past (or future) status with the same query. I think that's pretty awesome.

Suppose a customer buys a 3-month membership today. So you insert a status of Active with an effective date of today and another with a status of Arrears (or Lapsed or whatever) with an effective date 3 months from today.

- If the customer renews in that time period, update the future record and add another 3 months (or whatever term they bought) and everything continues to work fine.
- If the customer does nothing, the status will continue to show Active until the tick of the clock that brings it up to the date/time of the "future" entry. At that point, that status becomes current and it is the status that will be returned in the above query.